# Imagen en position fixed no funciona

Tags: html, css

En el `footer` tengo unas imágenes que representan las redes, de la cual la imagen de WhatsApp quiero ponerla fija a medida que se hace scroll. Utilizo `position: fixed` y no me funciona, ¿podrían ayudarme por favor? No se que estoy haciendo mal:

```css
.footer {
  background-color: white;
}

.flote {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <hr>
  <p class="p">
    Contactanos
    <br>
    Callle 123, Paris, Francia
    <br>
    Telefono: 0800-666-9696
  </p>
  <img class="img" src="../multimedia/francelogo.jpg" alt="francelogo">
  <div>
    <img src="../multimedia/iconos/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
    <img src="../multimedia/iconos/llamada-telefonica.png" alt="telefono">
    <img src="../multimedia/iconos/email.png" alt="email">
  </div>
  <div class="flote">
    <img src="../multimedia/iconos/whatsapp.png" alt="whatsapp">
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Agrega todo el código HMTL y CSS para poder reproducir el problema, ya que replicando el código en una pagina completa si funciona el fixed, o en su defecto explica mejor que es lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: por favor también agregar una imagen de lo que obtienes con ese código

Comment: Para que funcione, `flote` debe estar fuera de `footer`. El contenedor padre de `flote` debe ser el `body`.